# index.php loading continuesly even after successful login

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

In my code even after successful login the index page is not displayed and the browser keeps on loading(loading icon loads continuously)

NOTE: after logging in the other pages are accessible but index.php is alone loading but the same code works perfectly in windows environment

i have tried removing the onload function and the corresponding javascript code but still the problem persists.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    define('TITLE',"Dashboard| LBC");

    $companyName = "LiveByCode";
    function strip_bad_chars( $input ){
    $output = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $input);
    return $output;
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']))
{
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}

include 'includes/HTML-head.php';
?> 
    <link href="css/list-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/loader.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onload="pageLoad()">
    
    <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <img src='img/500.png' id='loader-logo'>
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="loader__bar"></div>
            <div class="loader__bar"></div>
            <div class="loader__bar"></div>
            <div class="loader__bar"></div>
            <div class="loader__bar"></div>
            <div class="loader__ball"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="content" style="display: none">
        
        <?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?> 
        
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3" >

                    <?php include 'includes/profile-card.php'; ?>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-7" >

                    <div class="text-center p-3">
                        <img src="img/200.png">
                        <h2 class='text-muted'>DASHBOARD</h2>
                        <br>
                    </div>


                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" id="forum-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#forum" role="tab" 
                             aria-controls="forum" aria-selected="true">Recent Forums</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" id="blog-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#blog" role="tab" 
                             aria-controls="blog" aria-selected="false">Recent Blogs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" id="poll-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#poll" role="tab" 
                             aria-controls="poll" aria-selected="false">Recent Polls</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" id="event-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#event" role="tab" 
                             aria-controls="event" aria-selected="false">Recent Events</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <br>

                    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="forum" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="forum-tab">

                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 my-3 text-white-50 bg-purple rounded shadow-sm">
                                <img class="mr-3" src="img/200.png" alt="" width="48" height="48">
                              <div class="lh-100">
                                <h1 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100">Latest Forums</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>  

                                <div class="row mb-2">

                                <?php
                                    $sql = "select topic_id, topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by, userImg, idUsers, uidUsers, cat_name, (
                                                select sum(post_votes)
                                                from posts
                                                where post_topic = topic_id
                                                ) as upvotes
                                            from topics, users, categories 
                                            where topics.topic_by = users.idUsers
                                            and topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
                                            order by topic_id desc, upvotes asc 
                                            LIMIT 6";
                                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    

                                    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
                                    {
                                        die('SQL error');
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);


                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                        {
                                            echo '<div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250">
                                                    <a href="posts.php?topic='.$row['topic_id'].'">
                                                    <img class="card-img-left flex-auto d-none d-lg-block blogindex-cover" 
                                                            src="img/forum-cover.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                                            </a>
                                                      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                                                        <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary text-center  ml-auto">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>'.$row['upvotes'].'
                                                        </strong>
                                                        <h6 class="mb-0">
                                                          <a class="text-dark" href="posts.php?topic='.$row['topic_id'].'">'
                                                            .substr(ucwords($row['topic_subject']),0,15).'...</a>
                                                        </h6>
                                                        <small class="mb-1 text-muted">'.date("F jS, Y", strtotime($row['topic_date'])).'</small>
                                                        <small class="card-text mb-auto">Created By: '.ucwords($row['uidUsers']).'</small>
                                                        <a href="posts.php?topic='.$row['topic_id'].'">Go To Forum</a>
                                                      </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>        


                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="blog" role="blog" aria-labelledby="blog-tab">

                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 my-3 text-white-50 bg-purple rounded shadow-sm">
                                <img class="mr-3" src="img/200.png" alt="" width="48" height="48">
                              <div class="lh-100">
                                <h1 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100">Latest Blogs</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div class="row mb-2">

                                <?php
                                    $sql = "select * from Blogs, users 
                                            where blogs.blog_by = users.idUsers
                                            order by blog_id desc, blog_votes asc
                                            LIMIT 6";
                                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    

                                    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
                                    {
                                        die('SQL error');
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);


                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                        {
                                            echo '<div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250">
                                                      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                                                        <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$row['blog_votes'].'
                                                        </strong>
                                                        <h6 class="mb-0">
                                                          <a class="text-dark" href="blog-page.php?id='.$row['blog_id'].'">'.substr($row['blog_title'],0,10).'...</a>
                                                        </h6>
                                                        <small class="mb-1 text-muted">'.date("F jS, Y", strtotime($row['blog_date'])).'</small>
                                                        <small class="card-text mb-auto">'.substr($row['blog_content'],0,40).'...</small>
                                                        <a href="blog-page.php?id='.$row['blog_id'].'">Continue reading</a>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <a href="blog-page.php?id='.$row['blog_id'].'">
                                                      <img class="card-img-right flex-auto d-none d-lg-block blogindex-cover" 
                                                            src="uploads/'.$row['blog_img'].'" alt="Card image cap">
                                                                </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>        


                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="poll" role="poll" aria-labelledby="poll-tab">

                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 my-3 text-white-50 bg-purple rounded shadow-sm">
                                <img class="mr-3" src="img/200.png" alt="" width="48" height="48">
                              <div class="lh-100">
                                <h1 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100">Latest Polls</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">

                              <?php

                                $sql = "select p.id, p.subject, p.created, p.poll_desc, p.locked, (
                                            select count(*) 
                                            from poll_votes v
                                            where v.poll_id = p.id
                                            ) as votes
                                        from polls p 
                                        order by votes desc
                                        LIMIT 5";

                                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    

                                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
                                {
                                    die('SQL error');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                    {

                                        echo '<a href="poll.php?poll='.$row['id'].'">
                                            <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
                                                <img src="img/poll-cover.png" alt="" class="mr-2 rounded div-img poll-img">
                                                <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray ">
                                                  <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark">'.ucwords($row['subject']).'</strong></a>
                                                      '.date("F jS, Y", strtotime($row['created'])).'
                                                       <br><br>
                                                       <span class="text-primary" >
                                                            '.$row['votes'].' User(s) have voted
                                                       </span>
                                                </p>
                                                <span class="text-right">';

                                        if($row['locked'] === 1)
                                        {
                                            echo '<br><b class="small text-muted">[Locked Poll]</b>';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo '<br><b class="small text-success">[Open Poll]</b>';
                                        }

                                        echo '</span>
                                                </div>';
                                    }
                               }
                            ?>

                            </div>    

                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="event" role="event" aria-labelledby="event-tab">

                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 my-3 text-white-50 bg-purple rounded shadow-sm">
                                <img class="mr-3" src="img/200.png" alt="" width="48" height="48">
                              <div class="lh-100">
                                <h1 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100">Upcoming Events</h1>
                              </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">

                              <?php

                                $sql = "select event_id, event_by, title, event_date, event_image
                                        from events
                                        where event_date > now()
                                        order by event_date asc
                                        LIMIT 5";
                                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);    

                                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
                                {
                                    die('SQL error');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                    {
                                        $earlier = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
                                        $later = new DateTime($row['event_date']);
                                        $diff = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a");

                                        echo '<a href="event-page.php?id='.$row['event_id'].'">
                                            <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
                                                <img src="uploads/'.$row['event_image'].'" alt="" class="mr-2 rounded div-img poll-img">
                                                <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
                                                  <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark">'.ucwords($row['title']).'</strong></a>
                                                  '.date("F jS, Y", strtotime($row['event_date'])).'<br><br>
                                                  <span class="text-primary" >'.$diff.' days remaining </span>
                                                </p>
                                                <span class="text-primary text-right">';

                                        if ($_SESSION['userLevel'] == 1 || $_SESSION['userId'] == $row['event_by'])
                                        {
                                            echo '<a href="includes/delete-event.php?id='.$row['event_id'].'&page=forum" >
                                                    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i>
                                                  </a>
                                                </span>';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo '</span>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</span>
                                                </div>';
                                    }
                               }
                            ?>

                            </div>    

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2">

                    <div class="text-center p-3 mt-5">
                        <a href="team.php" target="_blank">
                            <i class="creater-icon fa fa-users fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                        <p><br>THE CREATORS</p>
                    </div>

                    <a href="forum.php" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">KLiK Forum</a>
                    <a href="hub.php" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">KLiK Hub</a>
                    <br><br><br>
                    <a href="create-topic.php" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block">Create a Forum</a>
                    <a href="create-blog.php" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Create a Blog</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
    </div>
    

    
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    <script>
        var myVar;

        function pageLoad() {
          myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 4000);
        }

        function showPage() {
          document.getElementById("loader-wrapper").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>  
    
</body>
```

Comment: What does the javascript `pageLoad` function do? Have you got any `rewrite` rules in your server config / htaccess?

Comment: There's a redirect to the login if the session var is not set. Does the login.php redirect to index.php if the user is logged in? If so, maybe the session var isn't being set correctly? It could be redirecting to login.php and then back to index.php. Essentially an infinite loop.

Comment: But sir, exactly the same code works perfectly in windows environment.

Comment: And under which environment is this now?

Comment: The code works perfectly in windows environment but same code not working in ubuntu 20.04